# The best code for creating multiple histogram attributes on one graph in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, datagridview, data-visualization, histogram

I have got code that generates a 25 histogram on a 5 x 5 grid. However the code I have is really long and I need to make it much more simple as it is taking approx 75 lines.

I have spent a long time but this is way to much coding and there must be a much more simple solution. Hoping someone with knowledge can chop 80% of the data down.

[![Output of code][1]][1]

```
pp1<- data$PP1
pp2<-data$PP2
pp3<-data$PP3
KF1<-data$KF1
KF2<-data$KF2
KF3<-data$KF3
KF4<-data$KF4
KF5<-data$KF5
KF6<-data$KF6
KF7<-data$KF7
KF8<-data$KF8
Z4<-data$Z4
KF10<-data$KF10
Z1<-data$Z1
Z2<-data$Z2
Z3<-data$Z3
Z5<-data$Z5
F1<-data$F1
F2<-data$F2
F3<-data$F3
F4<-data$F4
F5<-data$F5
F6<-data$F6
T1<-data$T1
T2<-data$T2
X <- replicate(67, rnorm(15000))

p1 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = pp1,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p2 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = pp2,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p3 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = pp3,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p4 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF1,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p5 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF2,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p6 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF3,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p7 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF4,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p8 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF5,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p9 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF6,),
                                breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p10 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF7,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p11 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF8,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p12 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = Z4,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p13 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = KF10,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p14 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = Z1,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p15 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = Z2,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p16 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = data$Z3,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p17 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = Z5,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p18 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = F1,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p19 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = F2,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p20 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = F3,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p21 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = F4,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p22 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = F5,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p23 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = F6,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p24 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = T1,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")

p25 <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(aes(x = T2,),
                                 breaks = hist(X, plot = F)$breaks, colour="blue")



grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16, p17, p18, p19, p20, p21, p22, p23, p24, p25, nrow = 5, ncol = 5)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA7Fg.png
```

Answer (score 1):

ggplot works much more simply when you make your data longer (aka "tidy") where the different series you want to plot are denoted by a pair of columns, one marking which series it is and another marking the value, rather than many columns with separate series.

Here's an example with data we all have:

```
mtcars %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything())  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value))  + 
  geom_histogram()+ 
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

To understand the thinking around this approach, I recommend reading this chapter from R4DS: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html

Comment: This is my 1,000th answer! :-)